# Flutter HTTP calls using authorization fails but works in postman

Tags: flutter, dart, asp.net-web-api, authorization, postman

I am using Flutter 1.20.4, http 0.12.2 package and I am having an issue where my HTTP calls are successful in Postman but fail in a flutter. I came across a number of articles talking about issue with lower case HTTP headers and some older servers. I don't have that issue as I have tested postman with lower case. I have checked my bearer token on jwt.io and issuer matches the domain I am using. Any call made from flutter that uses authorization will return as "not authenticated" so it would come up with HTTP 302 (redirect to login by identity provider). Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...
var getProfileUrl = _identityApi + '/api/profile/get'; // TODO: CHANGE THIS
var accessToken = await _secureStorage.read(key: 'bearerToken');
var response = await http.get(getProfileUrl, headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $accessToken'
});
```

POSTMAN:
[image]

FLUTTER:
[image]

Comment: could it be that your backend is case-sensitive? In postman you wrote `bearer` while in flutter it's `Bearer` lol

Comment: @magicleon94 no, I tried, it is not case sensitive, you can use both "Bearer" or "bearer" it will still work with the server using postman

Comment: Hey, what is going on with this problem? It is 2022 and I'm having the same problem. This is such a basic functionality. Can't believe it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...
Map<String,String> _headers={
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept: 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'
};
var getProfileUrl = _identityApi + '/api/profile/get'; // TODO: CHANGE THIS
var accessToken = await _secureStorage.read(key: 'bearerToken');
var response = await http.get(getProfileUrl, headers: _headers);
```